# Message displays as "Element 'title' occurs too many times. How to use a single "Title" tag here?

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Message displays as "Element 'title' occurs too many times. How to use a single "Title" tag here?

```
        <head>
        ...
        @if (ViewBag.Title != null)
        {
            <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        }
        else
        {
            <title>MyTitle</title>
        }
        ...
        </head>
```

Comment: post the _layout view too

Comment: The code you show will only print one `<title>`. Show all relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this, which sets a local variable called title and uses the null coalescing operator to either set it to ViewBag.Title or to "MyTitle" if that's null.

```
@{var title = ViewBag.Title ?? "MyTitle";}
<title>@title</title>
```

But really you'd be better off setting the title in a ViewModel and not using ViewBag.

Comment: Working fine as expected. Thanks.